# iOS simulator change devices not working

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios-simulator

So I'm working through the BNR iOS objective c book, and I want to run a project on the iPad simulator. according to the book, I change the deployment device in the general settings for the project target as "universal," which I did. 
However when I run and switch to any iPad on the simulator I get drawn back to the main method of my project. The iPad does appear after a delay, but without the app I built. I've set all the views in my xibs to "inferred" but I still can't run my project on iPad.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the app is crashing.  it's possible if you created the app without setting it to universal it is missing a storyboard for iPad which would cause a crash and take you to that area.  You should look at the console logs and see what is happening.  There should be good information in there as to what is missing or why it's crashing right away.

Comment: I agree, but there is nothing in the console logs. There's just isn't much info on why it's happening.

Comment: can you paste what is in the console logs?  You can can also make sure to have a catch all breakpoint that might help as well.  not sure if that will help.